# How to mock HTTP2 server in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocking, http2, nock

Is there a way or any NPM library to Mock Http2 server. Usually I use [Nock](https://github.com/nock/nock) for mocking http server but it seems Nock [doesn't support](https://github.com/nock/nock/issues/1625) Http2

Answer (score 0):

Nock does not support HTTP2. [Feature request issue here](https://github.com/nock/nock/issues/1625).

I haven't used it, but in the issue there is a recommendation for [http2spy](https://github.com/bcoe/http2spy).

Comment: I did see the feature request and the suggestion doesn't really mock server it is for spying to make sure your request is made with correct params